# I have probleme in query builder SYMFONY

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, repository, query-builder

I want to search an user by "firstname" and "lastname"

so at first i have an input text where i put the lastname and firstname in the same  input

and second i have created this query

```
public function findListByName($name)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.firstname LIKE :name')
        ->orWhere('c.lastname LIKE :name)
        ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

updated with :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.firstname LIKE :name1')
        ->orWhere('c.lastname LIKE :name2')
        ->setParameter(':name1', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->setParameter('name2', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Now for example : 
i have in Data base the firstname = **"test"** and lastname=**"test2"**

and if i put in input this word:"test" or "test2" its work and return the user

if i put the word: **"test test2**" is not work(no results)

so who have a solution to solve this problem please

Comment: $name can have (firstname or lastname) or (firstname lastname) ?

Comment: $name can have (firstname lastname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because You are using two times  a param so try assign assign two param

eg: try  this way

```
public function findListByName($name)
{
      return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.firstname LIKE concat('%',:name1', '%') )
        ->orWhere('c.lastname LIKE concat('%',:name2', '%') )
        ->orWhere('concat(c.firstname,' ',c.lastname) LIKE concat('%',:name3', '%') )
        ->setParameters(array('name1'=> $name, 'name2' =>$name, 'name3'=>$name)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: this is solve 50% of probem, i can search only with the lastname or firstname, if i search "test test2" i receive no results

Comment: Same problem, can i do ('c.firstname IN :name) ?? or (':name like %c.firstname%) ??

Comment: I have this feeling, that op wants to search for "firstname lastname" by looking for "firstname lastname" in c.firstname, then by looking for "firstname lastname" in c.lastname. and surprise surprise, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jakumi   .could be so  . answer  updated .. with (partial) solution for your suggestion

Comment: @Jakumi  .tanks    seems your feeling is right ..  updated  somewhere

Answer (score 0):

you can check if $name have space

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
$isMultiple = false;
        if (strpos($name, ' ')) {
            $isMultiple = true;
            $name = explode(' ', $name);
        }
        if ($isMultiple) {
            $qb->andWhere('c.firstname LIKE :firstname')
                ->andWhere('c.lastname LIKE :lastname')
                ->setParameters('firstname', '%'.$name[0].'%')
                ->setParameters('lastname', '%'.$name[1].'%');
        } else {
            $qb->andWhere('c.firstname LIKE :name')
                ->orWhere('c.lastname LIKE :name')
                ->setParameters('name', '%'.$name.'%');
        }
```